# I am getting An Error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' in python WHAT IS IT?

Tags: python

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
What is this error/ I am learning python and getting this error now

```
def main():
    Dollars = dollars_to_float(input("How Much was the Meal?  "))
    Percentage = Percentage_to_float(input("What Percentage would you like to Tip?  "))
    Tip = Dollars * Percentage
    print(f"Leave ${Tip:.2f}")

def dollars_to_float(d):
    d = str(d)
    d = d.strip("$")
    d = float(d)
    print(d)

def Percentage_to_float(p):
    p = str(p)
    p = p.strip("%")
    p = float(p)
    print(p)
    
main()
```

This is very simple i just want to multiply Dollars and percentage

Comment: Your functions are returning `None` instead of the value that is printed.